# Cannot initialize variable with a placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

How does one go about creating variables with placeholders as initializers? The following graph breaks down with:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[node Placeholder_1 (defined at <ipython-input-10-b8d54264dc85>:3)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

My code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=())
d = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=())
b = tf.get_variable(name='b',initializer=d)
c=a+d
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a:5.,d:10.}))
```

The documentation on initializers in tensorflow says:

> Initializer for the variable if one is created. Can either be an initializer object or a Tensor. If it's a Tensor, its shape must be known unless validate_shape is False.

However if i comment out the line where i create b the code seems to run. My fetch is not even dependent upon b.

How do i go about creating variables that initialize according to some placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is described in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4920

My workaround would be to use `tf.assign` which would act like a lazy initializer, the shape would be before infered from `d` with `tf.zeros_like`. To get idea how does it work I made `b` a resource variable so it maintains state between `sess.run` calls.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(), name='a')
d = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(), name='d')
b = tf.get_variable(name='b', initializer=tf.zeros_like(d), use_resource=True)
b_init = tf.assign(b, d)
c=a+d
add_one = tf.assign(b,tf.add(b,tf.ones_like(b)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    print(sess.run([c, b_init], feed_dict={a:5.,d:10.}))    
    for i in range(10): 
        sess.run(add_one)
        print(sess.run([c,b], feed_dict={a:5.,d:10.}))
```

The output

```
[15.0, 10.0]
[15.0, 11.0]
[15.0, 12.0]
[15.0, 13.0]
[15.0, 14.0]
[15.0, 15.0]
[15.0, 16.0]
[15.0, 17.0]
[15.0, 18.0]
[15.0, 19.0]
[15.0, 20.0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you help me by confirming if the solution at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13351 works. i am unable to make it work

Comment: your solution assigns b equal to d on each iteration which is not the behavior intended.

Comment: I've edited the code to illustrate how you should use it. Split the `assign` and `get_variable` and use `assign` only before the loop. I've added `add_one` op that adds one to `b` and assigns it the value of addition to illustrate that it works. Moreover, I had to use resource variable so it maintains state between `sess.run` calls. Hope it clarifies things.